# simple date format with leading space instead of zero

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I need a simple Date format that can give leading space instead of zero for the    Day of month (d)

My current code using below date format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");

Restult i am getting is                        Wed Nov 04 05:55:15 2015
Restult i am getting for double digit days as  Wed Nov 14 05:55:15 2015
```

> Wed Nov  (space in place of zero)4 05:55:15 2015 for single digit day of month
>
> Wed Nov 14 05:55:15 2015 for double digit month of day.

Please help. is there any date format in java to get this format?

Comment: Convert it to String and use regex to remove the first 0 of the String. Simple enough.

Comment: A guess: change 'dd' to 'd': It might work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved with some logic.splitting the Date using spaces and appending the Space in front of day of month,if it is single digit and combine all.Otherwise no change.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

This prints out

```
Thu Nov 5 09:26:04 2015
```

Please note the small change in the date mask (removed one of the 'd' for the day number):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
```

Comment: These 2 things are normal formats.I have tried already.Need a space in place of zero if the day of month is single digit.

Comment: @Chaitu AFAIK there is no mask for that matter (an extra space when day of the month is one digit). Maybe you could format it manually using Calendar methods.

Comment: yeah,It seems that is the only choice.Thank you  @Averroes

Answer (score 0):

Use

new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");

here we have 'd' in place 'dd' so there won't be any leading zeros.

Regards.

Comment: I used the above format already.That will remove the zero. but i need a space in place of zero.